# iOS data storing mechanisms

Tags: ios, swift, local-storage, storage, persistent-storage

From my understanding, following are the data storing mechanisms:

1. UserDefaults - store small amount of data
2. Keychain - store sensitive data
3. Coredata - Framework built on top of SQLite for convenience
4. SQLite - preferred for complex querying mechanisms
5. plist serialization - saving plist file
6. Data.write(to: ) - saving data to the specified file

A. Is the above information true?

B. Also, does all these mechanisms store data in the Document Directory(or sub directories) path by default?

C. Does it use the local storage of the phone and is deleted once the app is uninstalled?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Sorry if its too basic, I have been reading hundreds of articles and it is confusing

Comment: I'd argue a little with #3.  Core Data frequently uses SQLite but not necessarily.  It's main point is having object persistence rather than having to translate between stored forms and runtime forms.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipMills! Also, my understanding that all these mechanism store data in the local directory(if not document directory) by default is correct or not? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are right with your understanding of data storing mechanisms.
But, apart from these 6 methods, another 2 methods which help to store data locally are:

i) Codable (protocol): used to save custom objects into a .plist file. It overcomes the drawback of the UserDefaults method that stores only built-in types data such as Int, String, Array, etc.

ii) Realm: It is a foster and easier database solution. You should also check its official documentation for more details.

All methods stores data into the Documents Directory. You can even print the path of document directory and open it in file manager to view data.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Appreciate your response!